# using python with django frame work problem

Tags: python-3.x

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')
def count(request):
    data= request.GET('full textarea')
    print(data)
    return render(request,'count.html',{'full text':data})
```

error=`'QueryDict' object is not callable`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly. Describe the problem, say what troubleshooting/research you have done, make a [mre], etc.

Comment: request.GET is an object quite similar to python dictionary and therefore it is not a function. So instead of request.GET('full textarea') use request.GET['full textarea']